# What are my options to force users of my API to implement a static method?

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using the BLoC pattern to implement firebase/firestore functionality. It seems common to implement a model, an entity (which is basically the model hold by the database) and a repository which handels requests of the program.

To convert the model into the entity and vice versa the model requires a `toEntity` and `fromEntity` method. I want my class to look like this:

```
@immutable
abstract class DatabaseModel {
  final id;
  DatabaseEntity toEntity();

  DatabaseModel({@required this.id});

  static DatabaseModel fromEntity(DatabaseEntity entity);
}
```

However, this is not possible. Dart does not allow static methods without a function body as mentioned in [Can one declare a static method within an abstract class, in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741737/can-one-declare-a-static-method-within-an-abstract-class-in-dart), based on the fact that static methods aren't inherited anyways.

I thought about implementing the `fromEntity` method as a member method of `DatabaseModel` model with an additional static method which calls the member method, like this:

```
abstract class DatabaseModel {
  final id;
  DatabaseEntity toEntity();

  DatabaseModel({@required this.id});

  static DatabaseModel createFromEntity(DatabaseEntity entity, DatabaseModel instance) {
    return instance.fromEntity(entity);
  }

  DatabaseModel fromEntity(DatabaseEntity entity);
}
```

But because of the following drawbacks I decided against using this method:

1. The inheriting class cannot longer be `@immutable`
2. Creating a new instance is not really straight forward since e.g. an object of `class YouTubeComment` would be instantiated like this - `DatabaseModel.createFromEntity(entity, YouTubeComment())`.
3. This requires the inheriting class to implement an empty constructor to create the instance.

Since it is not possible to implement a static method or an appropriate constructor, **Is there a way to signal the developer that it is intended to implement a static method?**