# In Dart, it is not possible to override a static method. but i can't understand output of this code

Tags: dart, methods, overriding

```
class Student {
  static void getDetails() {
    print('Get details method of Student class');
  }
}

class DartStudent extends Student {
  static void getDetails() {
    print('Get details method of DartStudent class');
  }
}

void main() {
  DartStudent.getDetails();
}
```

```
Output : Get details method of DartStudent class

Expected : Error. static method cannot be overriden.. or something wrong..


what's wrong with me?
getDetails() in DartStudent class is not overriding parent class's method?
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't override static methods.

The two static methods you declared there are in fact two different static methods, not the same, overriden one.

[Answer for a different question, but related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20741850/1673776):

> Dart doesn't inherit static methods to derived classes. So it makes no sense to create abstract static methods (without implementation).

Also check out [Why shouldn't static methods be able to be overrideable?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/330316/70146). It provides a thorough explanation of why static methods should not be overrideable in general.