# Dart: using named constructor on generic type in class template for deserializing multiple classes using a generic interface

Tags: flutter, dart, object, serialization

I want to create several objects that are serializable to a `Map` and deserializable from a `Map` so I can deserialize an entire `List` of such objects in other functions and methods. This is meant to avoid having to define a custom method for deserializing a `List` of objects for each type but instead being able to use a single one.

```dart
abstract class Serializable {
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap();
  Serializable.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map);
}

class Schema<T extends Serializable> {
  List<T> data = [];

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> serialize() {
    return data.map((e) => e.toMap()).toList(); // works fine
  }

  void deserialize(List<Map<String, dynamic>> data) {
    this.data = data.map((e) => T.fromMap(e)).toList(); // fromMap is not defined for type 'Type'
  }
}
```

This would be useful for example to store multiple objects of a class in a JSON file. As that storing part gets a bit complicated as it includes encryption I want to have a generic interface for serialization and deserialization.

```dart
class User extends Serializable {
  String username;
  
  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return { 'username': username};
  }

  @override
  User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) :
    username = map['username'],
}

Schema<User> users = Schema<User>();
users.deserialize(somemap);
```

However I cannot come up with a working solution for deserialization. If I use a generic type (that extends `Serializable`) I cannot access the named constructor. Defining `fromMap` as `static` doesn't work as well as static methods as you [can't have abstract static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74026216/dart-abstract-static-method).

Is there another way for achieving multiple classes that are deserializable using a generic interface?

Comment: This is not possible: `T.fromMap(e)`.  Since statics are not inherited, you can't have a runtime dispatch on a static... it must be known at compile time to point at the proper class.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz so there is no way to construct an "unknown type" even though we know it inherits from a known class?

Comment: You will need a factory constructor in the base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112130/creating-an-instance-of-a-generic-type-in-dart) about *Creating an instance of a generic type in DART*.

```dart
typedef ItemCreator<S> = S Function(Map<String, dynamic> map);

class Schema<T extends Serializable> {
  List<T> data = [];
  ItemCreator<T> fromMap;

  Schema(this.fromMap);

  void deserialize(List<Map<String, dynamic>> data) {
    this.data = data.map((e) => fromMap(e)).toList();
  }
}
```

In this solution when constructing `Schema` the `.fromMap` constructor is passed.

```dart
Schema<User> users = Schema<User>(User.fromMap);
```